# ASP.NET session is overwritten

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm in a situation where two calls at the same time write to the session (of an asp.net core application running on the old framework), and one of the session variables gets overwritten.

Given the following controller code, assume that the long session gets called first, 200 ms later the short session gets called, and 800 ms later (when the long session is done) the result of both sessions gets called.

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TestLongSession() {
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("testb", "true");

    // If we do this delay BEFORE the session ("testb") is set, then all is fine.
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    return Ok();
}

[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TestShortSession() {
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("testa", "true");

    return Ok();
}

[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TestResultOfBothSessions() {
    string a = HttpContext.Session.GetString("testa");
    string b = HttpContext.Session.GetString("testb");

    return Ok($"A: {a}, B: {b}");
}
```

The result of the final call (TestBothSessions) is `"A: , B: true"`.

The question is then: *Is there something I missed to make the session work (aka, return `"A: true, B: true"`)?*

Obviously, I could remove the delay and all is fine, but in the real application there's a call that potentially can take some time, and I prefer not to write the session variable at a later time (I guess I could with a bit of custom error handling, but then the problem still remains that I no longer trust the asp.net session to work with synchronous calls).

**Edit:** The typescript code that calls these endpoints from the browser:

```
this.service.testLongSession().subscribe(() => {
    this.service.testBothSessions().subscribe((result: string) => {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
setTimeout(() => {
    this.service.testShortSession().subscribe();
}, 200);
```

Comment: Why are you using session state to begin with? A better choice would be to make sure your app/requests are stateless. Could you explain the need to use it as maybe there is a better way to achieve the same goal without using it at all.

Comment: Is it API on a separate domain, or is it an endpoint in your MVC application? Most probably, this issue could be caused by race condition. Particularly, request 1 doesn't contain session cookie, therefore new session will be created. Request 2 doesn't contain session cookie as well, so a new session will be created for the second call.

Comment: How are you making the two requests? [Assuming JavaScript client within a browser...] if you're making the second request from the `.then()` of the first's promise, the first one should be completed before the second one is ever made. It sounds like you're not doing that.

Comment: Do you know what method of session state you're using? If it's cookies, for example, then setting the string won't actually happen until the call is completed and the cookie written, which means this would happen after your 1 second delay.

Comment: @Igor Making the application stateless would be a good thing, but also a very big change. Unfortunately we probably won't get there this year.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev All of these calls are called right after completion of a login request on the same domain. All are endpoints in the same MVC application.
I'm not sure if we set something in the session before these get called, I could test for that.

Comment: @madreflection I added in the relevant code sample. It's a javascript client in a browser yes.

Comment: @Darren Looks like it's cookies. From the startup's ConfigureServices method: `services.AddSession(options => { options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None; options.Cookie.Name = sessionOptions["CookieName"]; options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse(sessionOptions["IdleTimeout"]); });`

Comment: So in that case it won't actually be set until the response has been provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the behavior you observe is what the ASP.NET authors intended.  I look at the interfaces that session stores need to implement, namely [ISession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.isession?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and [ISessionStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.session.isessionstore.create?view=aspnetcore-2.2), and I see no synchronization mechanisms to prevent the overwriting of data during simultaneous requests.

The benefit of such a simple interface is that it's much easier to implement, and can be easily implemented by a variety of caches and databases.

ASP.NET 4 had a much more complex session store base class [SessionStateStoreProviderBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase?view=netframework-4.7.2) that included locking logic, but it was really challenging to implement.